# Application crashes in windows 8.1

Tags: c#, crash, system, windows-8.1, ntdll

One of my windows application in [.net 3.5] is installed in **windows 8.1**, to upload images.

I open the application, and I am using a dll to browse the images present in local disk to select and upload them.

Once after browsing the selection of image is done, **if I create a "New Folder" in my system, the application crashes -** it gives me exception as :

> > a problem caused the program to stop working correctly. 
> >     windows will close the program and notify...

I cross checked the event log, and here is a respective log added for the same :

```
Faulting application name: DesktopPhotoUploader.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x529f6471
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.16408, time stamp: 0x523d5305
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x00000000000f387c
Faulting process id: 0x8d0
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf2c7f30046a99
Faulting application path: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\7HWTE4KV.OXA\9K6HG17J.XZB\desk..tion_5f682daadb7f3a73_0002.0000_11d13f4927f45bcc\DesktopPhotoUploader.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 8ca29b6c-9872-11e3-8255-00219b71cec5
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Please let me what can be a reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Exception 0xc0000374 is `STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION`. It indicates your application manipulates the heap in an incorrect way and corrupts it. Is a bug in your code. You can analyze the dump to understand the problem. I recommend you get a copy of [Advanced Windows Debugging](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321374460), it has ample chapters dedicated to heap corruption. A common technique is to use GFlags, see [Detecting Heap Corruption Using GFlags and Dumps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2010/06/22/detecting-heap-corruption-using-gflags-and-dumps.aspx).

Comment: Thanks..I will go with that..I am not sure which area of my code is creating this problem..and is it like creating a folder uses Head memory..

Comment: I can reproduce the issue any time, with the test case above..Any idea on how to find the code base area causing this.

Comment: Use GFlags, as in the article linked.